# Obtain image via an API call to then save and serve up from local for repeated viewings

Tags: java, database, spring, database-design

I'm working on a webapp at the moment that will display a list of items.  The list is dynamic and can change between users.  A great analogy is to think of the objects as books, with the db backing it as the library.

My database for `Book` will contain a list of all books in the library.
-A user can add a book to their collection.
-If a user wants to add a new book to their collection they will also add it to the library.
-If a user wants to add a new book to their collection and it exists in the library, nothing will be added to the Book database.

Currently my table is incredibly simple: `Book(id, name)`.  I am able to access a plethora of information about these books via an API call, such as a front cover, number of pages etc etc.  I would like to store a subset of this information, especially the image url.

I think a sensible approach would be to alter my Book table so that it looks like: `Book(id, name, imageUrl, otherValue, idOfThisBookInApiCallTable)` the `idOfThisBookInApiCallTable` value will allow me to get other attributes as I need them, however I've two issues with this that I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Firstly is that this Table can easily get out of date with the APITable.  I don't expect there to be much change, if any, but the risk is there.

Secondly, the image being stored is my main concern, on a page where there might be 50 books, I'll making a call to the url of the image each time.  I think a sensible solution would be download the image locally and then serve it from then on repeated visits but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Might I ask if anyone can see any issues with this approach and/or suggest a better one please?  I have limited experience with db/web/app design so a little out of my depth here.

If saving the image locally is the correct approach, is there a 'best' way of doing this?
Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions/advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can share my 2 cents of a plausible design but I think the question is too broad and is mostly opinion-based. Let's address it by taking one thing at a time.

1. First regarding your `Book` table. Why not a `Library` table where you maintain the current state of your library with all the books that the library has at the moment.
2. Each user can hold a collection (a table etc with a one to many relation like user_id to list of book_ids or whatever) and then each user sort of owns a subset of bookIDs.
3. When adding a new book via user or via library (library can also add more books even if no particular user brought it in) then always add it to the library and if the user_id is known for the 'owner' of this book, add a relation for this user as well in the collection table
4. More details of a book can be stored separately in a `BookDetails` table.
5. Storage of images on your side is always a nice option and you don't want to get blocked by the API for over-usage when requesting over and over again. You can use some cloud storage like s3 where you can keep the images and then not bother the external api. S3 supports compression and caching so you can save lots of time and not have speed problems.

All the above points are just my opinion based on the information you gave on the question. The situation can of course be different for your use-case.

Comment: Hi there, I was a little worried about the question being closed before anyone had a chance to share. I need to find a site for opinions :D 
Thank you for taking the time to answer, your points are brilliant and I've either implemented what you suggested or will do so, I especially like the BookDetails table to help with housekeeping.
Re the image, I think I'll use the GCP variant of S3 as one of the project aims was to learn it more.  Assuming it shares similar attributes to s3 and I'd completely forgotten about hammering the api and being blocked.  Thank you!